# Javascript doesnt recognize anything from html (spring boot)

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot

This is my first time with spring boot. So, I have a simple index.html page, i go to it just through localhost:8080. I have some console.log() in my js under the html and they dont log a single thing. The api does work though, i tried it in postman and there is no problem. But it seems that the js doesnt recognize anything of the html. This is what the console.log() prints in the console:
[image]

As you can see they are empty. See my structure and my code below:

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="loginform">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Username">Username</label>
        <input name="username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter username" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input name="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
    <button id="login">Login</button>
</form>

<script>
    function login() {
        var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("#loginform"));
        var encData = new URLSearchParams(formData.entries());
        console.log(formData);
        console.log(encData);
        console.log(document.querySelector("#loginform"));

        fetch("/authenticate", {method: 'POST', body: encData})
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.ok) {
                    window.location.href = "/lingogame.html";
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    alert("Invalid Username or password");
                }
            })
            .then(myJson => window.sessionStorage.setItem("myJWT", myJson.JWT))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    var loginButton = document.querySelector("#login")
    if (loginButton) {
        loginButton.addEventListener("click", login);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may result from CSRF support of Spring Security. Check CSRF support is enabled or disabled, by default it is enabled by Spring Security. If enabled you must be send csrf_token with "X-CSRF-TOKEN" header with csrfToken value, otherwise it is not required.